# Cmd return value on single line

Tags: bash, variables

I know this question has been asked by others, but I'm not able to solve the issue I have. Let me explain.

I have a script (getWeather.sh) that pulls weather forecast and prints it to std out in a clean output as follows:

Sample output:

> 2023-05-19 14 90F 10 mph (S) Partly Sunny
> 2023-05-19 15 91F 10 mph (S) Mostly Sunny
> 2023-05-19 16 92F 15 mph (S) Chance Showers And Thunderstorms
> ...

Command executed by script:

```
curl -s -L "$( \
curl -s -L "https://api.weather.gov/points/$( \
curl -s -L "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=$( \
curl -s -L ipinfo.io | jq -r '"\(.city),\(.region)"')&polygon_geojson=1&format=jsonv2" | \
jq -r '"\(.[0].lat),\(.[0].lon)"')" | \
jq -r '.properties.forecastHourly')" | \
jq -r '.properties.periods[] | "\(.startTime):\t\(.temperature)F\t\(.windSpeed) (\(.windDirection))\t\(.shortForecast)"'| \
sed 's/Thunder/thunder/g; s/\(^[[:digit:]].*\)T/\1\t/g; s/:00:00-[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]:00://g; s/thunder/Thunder/g'|head -24
```

I will refer to the above command as 'CMD' for remainder of this message.

This works fine (if you live in the U.S.) and it gives a nicely formatted output of the weather for the next 24 hrs.

After some time of using this script, I've decided to make an enhancement to where it prints the min and max temperature rows at the end of the output.

> ...
> 2023-05-20 06 66F 10 mph (NNW) Mostly Cloudy
> 2023-05-20 07 66F 10 mph (NNW) Mostly Cloudy
>
> Min Temp: 2023-05-20 05 66F 10 mph (NNW) Mostly Cloudy
> Max Temp:   2023-05-19 16 92F 15 mph (S) Chance Showers And Thunderstorms

I tried to save the output of 'CMD' to a variable, res:

```
 res=`'CMD'`
```

so I can do some post-processing on the data, but everything is stored in a single line.

Problem 1:
The data in `$res` is in a single line and

```
echo $res
```

or

```
echo "$res"
```

makes no difference in terms of getting each line as when directing output from 'CMD' to std out.  **What am I doing wrong here?**

Problem 2:
To work around Problem 1, I tried to do an append to `$res` using a while read construct

```
'CMD'|while read LREAD; do res="$res `echo $LREAD`"; done
```

or

```
res='CMD'|while read LREAD; do res="$res `echo $LREAD`"; done
```

hoping to get separate rows of output. However, both result in

```
$> echo $res
echo
```

**Why does `$re`s end up containing `echo` and not the output of 'CMD'?**

I've solved the problem by redirecting output to file (not very elegant), and then cat the file and awk the file as follows:

```
'CMD'|while read LREAD; do echo $LREAD >> outres; done
```

and then print the result with

```
printf '%s\n\n%s\n'  "$(cat outres)" "$(cat outres|awk '{if(NR==1){min=$3; max=$3; minrow=$0; maxrow=$0}; if($3<min){min=$3; minrow=$0}; if($3>max){max=$3; maxrow=$0}}END{printf("Min Temp:\t%s\nMax Temp:\t%s\n",minrow, maxrow)}')"
```

Here's everything on a single row:

```
curl -s -L "$(curl -s -L "https://api.weather.gov/points/$(curl -s -L "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=$(curl -s -L ipinfo.io | jq -r '"(.city),(.region)"')&polygon_geojson=1&format=jsonv2" | jq -r '"(.[0].lat),(.[0].lon)"')" | jq -r '.properties.forecastHourly')" | jq -r '.properties.periods[] | "(.startTime):\t(.temperature)F\t(.windSpeed) ((.windDirection))\t(.shortForecast)"'|sed 's/Thunder/thunder/g; s/(^[[:digit:]].*)T/\1\t/g; s/:00:00-[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]:00://g; s/thunder/Thunder/g'|head -24|while read LREAD; do echo $LREAD >> outres; done ; printf '%s\n\n%s\n'  "$(cat outres)" "$(cat outres|awk '{if(NR==1){min=$3; max=$3; minrow=$0; maxrow=$0}; if($3<min){min=$3; minrow=$0}; if($3>max){max=$3; maxrow=$0}}END{printf("Min Temp:\t%s\nMax Temp:\t%s\n",minrow, maxrow)}')"
```

This is very inefficient and probably has a lot of room for improvement. I appreciate anyone taking time to read through all of this and giving me some directions.

Comment: `cmd1 | cmd2` usually runs both commands in a subshell, so changes to environment will not persist. However, bash has `shopt -s lastpipe` as a workaround in some cases

Comment: it's not clear (to me) what your actual `res=` looks like (can't distinguish between possible formatting issues and actual quoting); consider trying `res=$( CMD )` to see if that makes any difference; and you need to use double quotes (`echo "$res"`) to insure linefeeds are maintained in the output (also, try `typeset -p res`) to see contents

Comment: [Off-topic] First, you are fetching the current location (city+region) from ipinfo.io, then you are feeding it into nominatim.openstreetmap.org, just to extract the position (lat+lon) of it. But this info was also provided already in the response from ipinfo.io (just fetch `curl -sL ipinfo.io | jq -r '.loc'` instead).

Comment: @markp-fuso
res=$('CMD'); echo "$res" does indeed work. Thanks!!!

Comment: @pmf
Thanks for the optimization suggestion.

Comment: Some general notes: (1) Don't pipe two copies of jq together when you can have just one copy do all the work; `jq '.a.b'` is _far_ more efficient than `jq '.a' | jq '.b'`.

Comment: (2) Don't use `echo "$(anything)" | ...` -- you can just use `anything | ...` and leave out the `echo`. Similarly, `echo "$var" | ...` can become `<<<"$var" ...` and avoid the unnecessary pipeline. And definitely don't `echo "$(echo "$var")" | ...`, as it can always just be `echo "$var" | ...` or `<<<"$var" ...`

Comment: (3) Don't use backticks in shell. Ever, at all, for anything. They're a strictly worse alternative to modern command substitution syntax -- `$(...)` -- which has been standardized since the early 1990s. Backticks require you to use extra backslashes for quoting within them, and even more backslashes when you want to nest another command substitution inside them.

Comment: (4) http://shellcheck.net/ is your friend; it'll point out quoting bugs (of which there are a lot here) and many other classes of common problems. (5) Whitespace is your friend; keeping your code broken into lines with indentation that shows their nesting level makes it easier for readers to work through; "readers" includes future iterations of yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution in this very particular case is:

```
CMD | tee > >(...enhancements...)
```

But it doesn't entirely work in general (the best solution I have for the general problem is found below).

e.g. my `cmd` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
yes \
    | head -n 24 \
    | awk '{ printf("2023-05-%02d 06 %dF 10 mph (NNW) Mostly Cloudy\n", NR, NR); }' \
    | shuf
```

And when I run this with your `awk` command:

```
$ ./cmd | tee >(awk '{if(NR==1){min=$3; max=$3; minrow=$0; maxrow=$0}; if($3<min){min=$3; minrow=$0}; if($3>max){max=$3; maxrow=$0}}END{printf("Min Temp:\t%s\nMax Temp:\t%s\n",minrow, maxrow)}')
2023-05-22 06 22F 10 mph (NNW) Mostly Cloudy
2023-05-14 06 14F 10 mph (NNW) Mostly Cloudy
2023-05-03 06 3F 10 mph (NNW) Mostly Cloudy
2023-05-06 06 6F 10 mph (NNW) Mostly Cloudy
2023-05-20 06 20F 10 mph (NNW) Mostly Cloudy
2023-05-15 06 15F 10 mph (NNW) Mostly Cloudy
2023-05-07 06 7F 10 mph (NNW) Mostly Cloudy
2023-05-21 06 21F 10 mph (NNW) Mostly Cloudy
2023-05-11 06 11F 10 mph (NNW) Mostly Cloudy
2023-05-16 06 16F 10 mph (NNW) Mostly Cloudy
2023-05-12 06 12F 10 mph (NNW) Mostly Cloudy
2023-05-10 06 10F 10 mph (NNW) Mostly Cloudy
2023-05-17 06 17F 10 mph (NNW) Mostly Cloudy
2023-05-02 06 2F 10 mph (NNW) Mostly Cloudy
2023-05-13 06 13F 10 mph (NNW) Mostly Cloudy
2023-05-09 06 9F 10 mph (NNW) Mostly Cloudy
2023-05-01 06 1F 10 mph (NNW) Mostly Cloudy
2023-05-23 06 23F 10 mph (NNW) Mostly Cloudy
2023-05-05 06 5F 10 mph (NNW) Mostly Cloudy
2023-05-08 06 8F 10 mph (NNW) Mostly Cloudy
2023-05-18 06 18F 10 mph (NNW) Mostly Cloudy
2023-05-04 06 4F 10 mph (NNW) Mostly Cloudy
2023-05-19 06 19F 10 mph (NNW) Mostly Cloudy
2023-05-24 06 24F 10 mph (NNW) Mostly Cloudy
Min Temp:   2023-05-10 06 10F 10 mph (NNW) Mostly Cloudy
Max Temp:   2023-05-09 06 9F 10 mph (NNW) Mostly Cloudy
```

(Side note: I think you have a bug in the min/max finding logic).

Explanation:

`tee` reads every input line, and appends it to whatever file it is given in the command line, plus to stdout.
That print to stdout is how you get the first part, the 24 weather lines.

But that file we gave it is `>(...some shell commands...)`.
The syntax `>()` creates a pipe that you can write to, but with a file representation that you can pass to commands. (For example, on my machine if I run `echo >(bash)`, It prints `/dev/fd/63`.) So we're basically running something like `tee /dev/fd/63`, which will cause `tee` to feed the input into that pipe `/dev/fd/63`, and bash sets up `/dev/fd/63` as stdin for the shell commands, which in this case are our `awk` command that print the 2 min/max lines.

---

Unfortunately, this doesn't always work correctly.

`tee` works on pipes, so it doesn't know when the input will end, and every time it reads a line it emits it to both stdout and the file (the pipe) in parallel.

Here's a demo where it doesn't work:

```
yes \
    | head -n 10000 \
    | sed 's/y/hello/' \
    | tee >(sed 's/hello/world/')  \
    | grep -vx -e hello -e world
```

Here, CMD prints 10,000 times "hello", and the enhancement is to additionally print "world" for every "hello". The `grep -vx` is just to validate that we didn't print anything else.

Output:

```
heworld
worlllo
d
wohello
hellrld
o
heworld
worlllo
d
wohello
herld
llo
worlhello
helld
woo
herld
llo
worlhello
helld
woo
rld
```

We get this garbage once in a while because the printing of "hello" by `tee` and the printing of "world" by `sed` are essentially happening in parallel.

In the case of the particular `awk` command that this question is asking about:

```
awk '
    {
        if(NR==1){min=$3; max=$3; minrow=$0; maxrow=$0}; if($3<min){min=$3; minrow=$0}; if($3>max){max=$3; maxrow=$0}
    }
    END{
        printf("Min Temp:\t%s\nMax Temp:\t%s\n",minrow, maxrow)
    }
'
```

You can see that `awk` won't print anything until the very end, at which point `tee` already printed everything to stdout, so there will be no parallel printing.

---

Solving the more general problem, where the enhancement commands might print at any time, is actually not easy.

We have a few problems:

- We want to process stdin twice, but not in parallel. Therefore, we have to read all of stdin and save it somewhere.
- We want to process stdin by 2 different programs, so they need to run one after the other and not in parallel.
- If we just run the 2 processes one after the other, that's not really a single line anymore. If we want to keep it a single line (i.e. a single shell pipeline), we need to use 2 copies of stdin in 2 streams, but still somehow not process them in parallel.

The best solution I came up with is to abuse stderr as the second stream:

```
yes \
    | head -n 10000 \
    | sed 's/y/hello/' \
    | xargs -0 bash -c '
        echo -n "$1"; echo -n "$1" > /dev/stderr
    ' bash0 \
    2> >(sed 's/hello/world/') 
    | grep -vx -e hello -e world
```

This produces an empty output, and if we remove that `grep -vx`, it prints 10,000 "hello" followed by 10,000 "world", as expected.

It works as follows:

- stdin is 10,000 lines of "hello".
- Read all of stdin as a single string - `xargs -0` will read everything until `\0` or end-of-file is encountered, so in this case - everything.
- `xargs` makes all of stdin the first argument to the given command - `bash` in our case.
- The syntax `bash -c command value0 value1` runs the bash command `command` with the shell name being `value0` and the first and only argument being `value1`. `value0` is `bash0`, and it doesn't matter.
- `value1` is stdin. Within the bash command, we refer to it by `$1`.
- Our bash command first writes stdin (`$1`) to stdout by doing `echo -n "$1"`.
- Then our bash command writes `$1` to stderr so that we can do further enhancement with the same pipeline without having to care about our first copy of stdin that was already printed to stdout.
- We redirect stderr to a shell command independently of stdout, by doing `2> >(...)`
- Our shell command for processing stderr is the enhancement code (`sed 's/hello/world/'`. Note that this process is not a subprocess of the `xargs` process or its subordinate `bash` process, so its stdout is the regular stdout.

---

As for the few other shell syntax questions in the original post:

This syntax:

```
'CMD'|while read LREAD; do res="$res `echo $LREAD`"; done
```

Would cause the shell to run `CMD` and the `while` loop in 2 new shell processes, and in the new process `res` will be assigned, but in the shell process where you run the command, this variable remains untouched.

This syntax:

```
res='CMD'|while read LREAD; do res="$res `echo $LREAD`"; done
```

Again runs 2 processes, where `res` is assigned in both, but not in the shell where you run the command.

The correct syntax is:

```
res="$(CMD)"
```

You said:

> I tried to save the output of 'CMD' to a variable, res (res='CMD')
> ...
> Problem 1: The data in $res is in a single line [...]

With neither `` res=`CMD` ``  nor `res="$(CMD)"` that would be the case as long as you print it with `echo "$res"` and not `echo $res` - I am not able to reproduce this issue with `echo "$res"`.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for taking time to explain this so well. I completely understand where you're going. (Ab)Using stderr is very clever. Thanks again, mate!